# showing run time error 3134 in access from

Tags: ms-access, vba

it is giving me an run time error 3134 syntax  error in insert into statement while clicking  on the control.

```
Private Sub CmdAddNew_Click()
'add data to table
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblemployee(,firstname,lastname,Address,city)" & _
"VALUES('" & Me.txtfirstname & "','" & Me.txtlastname & "','" & Me.txtaddress & "','" &     Me.txtcity & "')"
```

Comment: You have an SQL injection problem there. What will happen if `txtlastname` is "O'Hara"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tblemployee(,firstname`

Extra comma here?

Comment: i have removed the extra comma , it is not giving me error but the control is not working @sam092

Comment: add dbFailOnError as second parameter n call of Execute